# Trying to create family tree from dictinoary

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, binary-tree, nested-lists

I am trying to create "child,parent" dictionary from my dictionary. How can i achieve that?

Here is my dict:

`{"Sıdıka":[{"Aziz":[{"Ahmet":[{"Kuzey":[]}],"Öznur":[{"Elif":[]},{"Yiğit":[]}],"İlknur":[{"Nurullah":[]},{"Büşra":[]}],"İlker":[{"Melih":[]}]}]}]}`

Left to right ancestors are growing. Sıdıka is grand grand grand grand mother, aziz is her son. And "ahmet, öznur,ilknur,ilker" are "aziz"s children etc. etc.
I want a dictionary something like this:

```
{'Sıdıka':[{'Aziz':[{'Ahmet':[{'Kuzey':[]}],'Öznur':[{'Elif':[]},{'Yiğit':[]}],'İlknur':[{'Nurullah':[]},{'Büşra':[]}],{'İlker':[{'Melih':[]}]}]
```

I think i need a very good algorithm for this. Any help?

Comment: You are definitely going to need a special algorithm to get *that* output from the given input.

Comment: @Mark because of my aim can be described simply i thought algorithm will be simple too

Comment: I was talking about the converting `Sıdıka` to `Smith`, etc. It's helpful to show the **actual** output you want.

Comment: @Mark oh sure, let me edit the question,

Comment: @j1-lee it wont be deep, but still i couldnt do the thing that you said (tried nested dicts), i just want to learn in "any" ways how can i do this

Comment: @j1-lee thanks anyway for your time =)

Comment: @Mark edited the question by the way sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion for the task:

```py
d = {
    "Sıdıka": ["Aziz"],
    "Aziz": ["Ahmet", "Öznur", "İlknur", "İlker"],
    "Ahmet": ["Kuzey"],
    "Öznur": ["Elif", "Yiğit"],
    "İlknur": ["Nurullah", "Büşra"],
    "İlker": ["Melih"],
}


def get_tree(root):
    return {root: [get_tree(v) for v in d.get(root, [])]}


print(get_tree("Sıdıka"))
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "Sıdıka": [
        {
            "Aziz": [
                {"Ahmet": [{"Kuzey": []}]},
                {"Öznur": [{"Elif": []}, {"Yiğit": []}]},
                {"İlknur": [{"Nurullah": []}, {"Büşra": []}]},
                {"İlker": [{"Melih": []}]},
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So what if i want to find "Sıdıka"'s level? For example she is melih's mothers fathers mother, so 3. level. How can i achive that?

Comment: @canovichh I suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow, to not clutter the comment section. Post there what you have and what have you tried.